# Why aren't locked posts viewable in the Questions list?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, question-lists, historical-lock

I can't seem to find my locked ee.SE question anywhere on the Questions list on EE.se, despite it showing up on the Hot Questions list on SE and the active list on All Questions.

Is this just a bug or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lock used on your question is the "historical significance" lock. As its description says, it marks a question that is not considered to be an on-topic question on the site despite its score or answers. It's kept around because its content overall is valuable, but it shouldn't be used as an excuse to post *new* similar questions.

With that in mind, questions locked for that reason (and not others) are hidden from the questions list so they can't be stumbled upon by new users quite as readily.

Comment: But what benefit is there from hiding it from other users, if the content overall is valuable?

Comment: @euphoriaoverlord Valuable doesn't mean "welcome on the site again". Questions like this aren't deleted because the overall information they provide outweighs the desire/need to keep the site on-topic. Check out the [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/) Nicael linked. It does a better job of explaining this.

Answer (score 2):

[Historical lock](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/) completely removes a question from a usual question list.

> For now, we’ve provided a “Historical Artifact” lock that completely freezes a question and its answers, preventing all further editing, voting, answering, and flagging. It will also **remove it from the usual lists of questions on the site** while allowing it to remain fully accessible and visible to everyone with a link to it.