# Why does this "historical locked" question show up in the Questions list, by mine doesn't?

Tags: discussion, bug, locked-questions, historical-lock

[Don't close questions where the user has requested that it not be closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed)

Question has a historical lock:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: help center.

My question:

[Why would clipping a wire cause a bomb to explode?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/129548/why-would-clipping-a-wire-cause-a-bomb-to-explode)

Historical lock:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: help center.

The first question can be viewed in the questions list.  From an answer I got in this question: [Why aren't locked posts viewable in the Questions list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239779/why-arent-locked-posts-viewable-in-the-questions-list), it seems to imply that historical locks on questions make it so that you need a direct link to the question to view it. On [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), my question has altogether disappeared from the Questions list.  Here on Meta.SE, that question seems to have not.

Comment: Where how it what why show up?

Comment: My question doesn't show up in the Questions list, and from a previous question, the answer said that historical locks on questions make those questions only viewable by direct url.  The Meta.SE question is the same situation, but can be viewed through the Questions list, thus contradicting the previous answer.

Comment: @euphoriaoverlord sure you don't mean search results? Those are not affected by the locking.

Comment: What's the screenshot of where it shows up? Maybe Questions list isn't what you Questions list

Comment: Okay, on M.SE, I clicked on the Questions tab, then sorted by Votes, then clicked on the very last index (4563) to find the first question.  On Electrical Engineering, I clicked on the Questions tab, then sorted by Votes, then clicked on page 2 or page 3, but my question appears nowhere.

Comment: From the [faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for): *Note that historical locked questions on meta sites are not hidden in this manner, though their answers are still frozen in the same fashion* so guess that for this matter, MSE is considered a meta site.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ah, didn't see that there. Thought it was maybe from the downvotes and the close votes. But then again, why is the behavior on meta considerably different than the main site? Anyhow, if you post an answer I'd gladly accept it.