# Add a visual indication in the question list that a question is locked

Tags: feature-request, locked-questions

This is not a duplicate of [the question asked here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239779/why-arent-locked-posts-viewable-in-the-questions-list).

When a question is a duplicate, or on hold, you can see a sign, e.g. `[on hold]`, next to the title in the list of questions, so that you don't waste your time clicking on it unless you really want to.

When it is locked, however, I don't see a [locked] sign. It would be appropriate given that there is really no way to interact with a locked question, you can't even upvote comments.

I first asked this question [on meta Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6623/why-cant-we-see-from-question-list-that-a-question-is-locked), where a significant number of questions get locked because they come from ongoing contests. I was advised to post it here as well since it's not an issue that can be solved on one particular SE site.

Comment: FYI, this *is* possible on the Android app; locked and protected questions show as "[locked]" and "[protected]" in question lists there.